# Have text length limit when I insert new row into table in Azure

Tags: text, azure, azure-sql-database

I set my column `comment` as `Nvarchar(500)`

but when I try to insert a new row (exec store procedure from Azure), the comment column should contain about 200 characters, but it actually only contain 50 characters.

any suggestion?

Comment: have you checked the length of the variable in the stored procedure?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please update your question to include code (e.g. your sproc). Also: are you using Windows Azure SQL DB, or SQL Server in a Virtual Machine (not that it would make a difference in this case, but still useful to know)? Again, please update your question with this information.